# How to simplify a Bootstrap menu?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to make a class that holds several other classes?
In the Bootstrap menu, there are many anchor tags with the same multiple classes such as:

```
 <a class="nav-item nav-link" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
```

To something like:

```
 <a class="consolidate-name" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
```

Comment: You can't do that in CSS but when you should use the LESS file, then you able to do this type of thing in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't do that in CSS** but when you should use the **LESS** file, then you able to do this type of thing in your project.

Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

You will have to **import the bootstrap.less** file first.

[Click](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-less) to step Install Bootstrap Less

For a Example, *the syntax is*:

```
.consolidate-name {
    .nav-item;
    .nav-link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

basically, nav-item, nav-link, navbar-brand, etc are basic predefined classes,
why we using these classes?

1. avoid the extra time to write CSS
2. these classes are stable, which means it tested very well.
3. use these classes, archive responsive class.

   ```
          -----note----
   ```

your question was is there any problem to change bootstrap class?
the **answer was no problem,**
if you are in very good in CSS, then you can change or simplify any codes, and even you can develop your own CSS frameworks